# How to select nodes with XPath in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xpath

Simple question, I just want to select the text from the <Template> tag.  Here's what I have, but the Xpath doesn't match anything.

```
public static void TestXPath()
{
    string xmlText = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>";
    xmlText += "<Properties xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties\" xmlns:vt=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes\">";
    xmlText += "<Template>Normal</Template>  <TotalTime>1</TotalTime>  <Pages>1</Pages>  <Words>6</Words>";
    xmlText += "</Properties>";

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(new System.IO.StringReader(xmlText));

    foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Template"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", node.Name, node.InnerText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to use an [`XmlNamespaceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx) because the Template element is in a namespace:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(new System.IO.StringReader(xmlText));
XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("ns", 
    "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties");

foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//ns:Template", manager))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", node.Name, node.InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

That is a namespace issue; you need to get the name-table, pick an alias, and use that in your query. Or perhaps (in this case) try `GetElementsByTagName`.

```
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("x",
    "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties");
foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//x:Template", mgr))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", node.Name, node.InnerText);
}
```

Or:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Template"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", node.Name, node.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: I had no idea you had to pick an arbitrary alias to properly resolve XPath queries in this manner!  Thanks for the info Marc.

Answer (score 4):

Here your xpath expression requires a namespace resolution. you have to instanciate a XmlNamespaceManager and use it in your SelectNodes.

this sample should work

```
    public static void TestXPath()
    {
        string xmlText = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>";
        xmlText += "<Properties xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties\" xmlns:vt=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes\">";
        xmlText += "<Template>Normal</Template>  <TotalTime>1</TotalTime>  <Pages>1</Pages>  <Words>6</Words>";
        xmlText += "</Properties>";

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(new System.IO.StringReader(xmlText));

        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("res", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties");

        foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//res:Template", nsmgr))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", node.Name, node.InnerText);
        }
    }
```

you can also get the default namespace by using and write

```
string s = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", s);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need the namespace here anyway? just get rid of these

```
xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties\" 
xmlns:vt=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes\"
```

and your selection will work.