# Simple XPath query: no results

Tags: c#, .net, html, xml

I want to parse the HTML of a website in my C# program.

First, I use the [SGMLReader](http://developer.mindtouch.com/en/docs/SgmlReader) DLL to convert the HTML to XML. I use the following method for this:

```
XmlDocument FromHtml(TextReader reader)
{
    // setup SGMLReader
    Sgml.SgmlReader sgmlReader = new Sgml.SgmlReader();
    sgmlReader.DocType = "HTML";
    sgmlReader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;
    sgmlReader.CaseFolding = Sgml.CaseFolding.ToLower;
    sgmlReader.InputStream = reader;

    // create document
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
    doc.XmlResolver = null;
    doc.Load(sgmlReader);
    return doc;
}
```

Next, I read a website and try to look for the `header` node:

```
var client = new WebClient();
var xmlDoc = FromHtml(new StringReader(client.DownloadString(@"http://www.switchonthecode.com")));
var result = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("head");
```

However, this query gives an empty result (count == 0). But when I inspect the results view of xmlDoc.DocumentElement, I see the following:

[image: VS watch]

Any idea's why there are no results? Note that when I try another site, like http://www.google.com, it works.

Comment: There's a namespace on `head` -- you can see it in the screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select using the namespace explicitly, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100156/how-to-select-nodes-with-xpath-in-c).

```
XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");

doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("ns:head", manager);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead. It's an open source HTML parser

Comment: Technically, TheCodeKing gave the correct answer to the question. However I've tried your suggestion and it works easier because no namespaces are needed! Thanks.